# Extracting stack trace from minidump

Tags: stack-trace, minidump

I'm trying to figure out how can I read a stack trace of the faulting thread from minidump file on windows. Is there an easy solution? I can't find one.

Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I need to do it programmaticaly.

Should I use DbgEng to do it?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`k`](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#15_call_stack)

Programmaticaly: [IDebugControl::GetStackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for live process.

Another alternative is to embark on the [Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) wagon, but that changes the entire process, including the generation of dumps.